# How to register dynamics workflow activity using Power Platform Tools in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, plugins, microsoft-dynamics

Given the number of issues/bugs with Plugin Registration Tool, I've decided to try Power Platform Tools on Visual Studio. But given the relative newness of this tool, there really aren't a lot of tutorials, blogs, videos explaining how to use it. Has anyone tried registering a Workflow Activity using this tool? If yes, I could really use your help as to how. And why does it expect you to register anything in association with an entity? On the Plugin Registration Tool, you didn't need any association to an entity.